# MultiThreading timer efficiency

Tags: java, mysql, multithreading, processing-efficiency, memory-efficient

Hello everyone once again i would like to get some suggestions about my code efficiency

```
Thread  thread= new Thread (new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
        while(true){       
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;

        try {
            Connection con = DatabaseConnection.getConnection();
              ps = con.prepareStatement("SELECT Datacolum FROM accounts WHERE id = ? ");
              ps.setInt(1, 2);
              rs = ps.executeQuery();
              if(rs.next()) { //there is a row
                  LConnection = rs.getInt("Datacolum");

                   }

              ps.close();

    } catch (SQLException ex) {}

     for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) { //Timer To Recheck Connection database 10 seconds
             try{
                Thread.sleep(1000);
             }catch(InterruptedException ex){}}
if (LConnection !=1) {
        user.Kick(5, "8", 5);
        thread.stop();

    }}}});
```

i would really like to know if such Thread will not hurt the rest of the code outside it while this code is looping every 10 seconds, maybe if there is a more efficient Timer Code i would be more then grateful to know. i want this thread to work as long as the user is connected to my application

the code does the next operation starting Looping thread>>it checks a colum>> wait 10 seconds >>enter if operator>>if not met >>Repeat Code

Open for suggestions
Sincerely yours,
Ex

Comment: why use a for loop for sleeping, why not Thread.sleep(10000)

Comment: actually good point i kinda missed that lol

Comment: My only comment is to not use thread.stop().  Just return from the method.  In this case the normal reasons for not calling stop may not apply but it is just poor style, especially when, in this case, you don't need it.

Comment: You most likely have bigger problems, like you are not closing your `Connection` so you will quickly run out.  A thread doesn't need to call `stop()` on itself, you can just use `return;`